# LinkButton Redirection with Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make some simple code to increate a number in a DataBase with a repeater `onitemcommand` that sends a id & a commandname.

The code to increase the `int` in the Database works fine, but when I then try to add a redirection to "The Article page" where you can read the whole article.

So my question how can I redirect with a `LinkButton` & make Query Strings in the redirection as shown below in a `<a>` (HTML5) tag inside the `linkbutton` // If I add the `<a>` (HTML5) tag it doesn't update the `int` in database // if I remove the `<a>` (HTML5) tag it will update the database `int` but won't redirect with the Query Strings.

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_Frontpage" OnItemCommand="Repeater_Frontpage_ItemCommand" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Visit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("news_id") %>' runat="server"><a href="Article.aspx?category_id=<%# Eval("fk_categories_id") %>&amp;news_id=<%# Eval("news_id") %>">Read More</a></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>




protected void Repeater_Frontpage_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Visit")
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Helpers.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        int userId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE News SET news_visits = news_visits + 1 WHERE news_id =" + userId;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use Response.Redirect?

Comment: If you decide to use Response.Redirect in the code behind i can't use Eval to make query strings.

Comment: You have the newsID, you have the data in the Repeater DataSource, you'll be able to build the url from there

Comment: Would you be able to show how? I'm still not a master at C#.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `ItemIndex` as a CommandArgument

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>'
```

And then you can get the row from the Repeater DataSource

```
protected void repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.CommandName == "Visit")
    {
        var rowIndex = (int)e.CommandArgument;
        //Here I am assuming that your data source is a DataTable
        var row = ((DataTable)repeater.DataSource).Rows[0];
        var newsID = row.Field<int>("newsID");
        var categoriesID = row.Field<int>("fk_categories_id");

        Response.Redirect($"Article.aspx?category_id={categoriesID}& amp;news_id={categoriesID}");
        Response.Write($"Do something with {e.CommandArgument}");
    }

}
```